# Trying to cast box2d to geometry gives back only numbers

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a query where I use `select ST_Extent(geometries)` which returns a box2d object. I would like to cast it back to a geometry object since that is what I need but I was unable to do so with `select ST_Extent(geometries)::geometry` which returned only a set of numbers. I was also unable to find any alternatives. Also using another ST function would work for me but I was unable to find something suiting

Comment: That set of numbers is the *bytea* resentation of a `GEOMETRY` type. Geometries are byte encoded types by design, and all `ST` functionality is built on top of them - so for all intent and purpose, those numbers are correct. There are functions to deserialize the byte encoding into human readable format, primarily `ST_AsText`/`ST_AsEWKT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this query:

```
select st_extent(geom) as box,
  st_extent(geom)::geometry as g1,  
  st_asewkt(st_extent(geom)::geometry) as geom 
from osopen_zoomstack.boundaries
```

gives me the expected results.

```
"BOX(315261.25 185879.45,398017.01 657601.49)"  
"0103000000010000000500000000000000F53D13419A999999BBB0064100000000F53D1341AE47E1FA82112441A4703D0A044B1841AE47E1FA82112441A4703D0A044B18419A999999BBB0064100000000F53D13419A999999BBB00641"
"POLYGON((315261.25 185879.45,315261.25 657601.49,398017.01 657601.49,398017.01 185879.45,315261.25 185879.45))"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :D exactly what I was looking for but wasn't able to find nowhere :)